# Compressing with GZipStream

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to understand why my code doesn't execute as desired. It creates a GZipStream,  and then saves the object as compressed file on my hard drive, but the saved file is always 0 bytes.

Now I know how to [save a file using GZipStream](http://www.dotnetperls.com/gzipstream), but, my question is not how to do it. My question is purely why does this code save 0 bytes (or why FileStream works and memory doesn't).

```
private void BegingCompression()
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(this.fileName);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        ms.ReadByte();
        using (FileStream fs =new FileStream(this.newFileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
        {
            zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

In regards to the source code, `this.fileName = c:\Audio.wav` and the `newFileName` is `c:\Audio.wav.gz` (but have also tried `c:\audio.gz`)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- You do not need a MemoryStream because `bytes` already has the data to compress.
- `ms.ReadByte()` should not be used.
- When creating the `zipStream` the output file stream should be used.

Try this:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(this.fileName);
using (FileStream fs =new FileStream(this.newFileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
{
     zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

**EDIT**

The original code creates a zero length file because you do not write to the file stream.

Comment: You may also want to consider converting to MP3; see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5901/C-MP3-Compressor

Answer (score 13):

When you use `GzipStream` or `DeflateStream` from the `System.IO.Compression` namespace, the `Stream` you supply in the *constructor* will be **written to** for **compression** and **read from** in **decompression**.

Since you are trying to *compress* the data here, using the `MemoryStream` is incorrect as you are not trying to compress to it, but rather use it as a data source. So your `MemoryStream` should be the input `Stream` and the `FileStream` is your output.

I highly recommend you using `MemoryStream` as a data source over the raw `byte[]` because `Stream` has a lot more versatility and application (`FileStream`, `NetworkStream`, `CryptoStream`, etc.)

Here are some examples using the `async`/`await` pattern:

```
public static async Task CompressToFileAsync(byte[] buffer, 
                                             string outputFile)
{
  using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    await CompressToFileAsync(inputStream, outputFile);
}

public static async Task CompressToFileAsync(Stream inputStream, 
                                             string outputFile)
{
  using (var outputStream = File.Create(outputFile))
  using (var gzip = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
  {
    await inputStream.CopyToAsync(gzip);
    gzip.Close();
  }
}

public static async Task<MemoryStream> DecompressFromFileAsync(string inputFile)
{
  var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

  using (var inputStream = File.Open(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
  using (var gzip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
  {
    await gzip.CopyToAsync(outputStream);

    gzip.Close();
    inputStream.Close();

    // After writing to the MemoryStream, the position will be the size
    // of the decompressed file, we should reset it back to zero before returning.
    outputStream.Position = 0;
    return outputStream;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Always call `GzipStream.Close()` before you close the *input* or *output* `Stream`. It does some final buffer flushing when closing/disposed and if the *input* or *output* is closed first it will throw an exception when it tries to do so. (This also applies to `DeflateStream`)

Comment: You say always call `GzipStream.Close()`, but the docs themselves don't call it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=net-5.0

Comment: The docs is incorrect, just tried it. If you don't call Close() the compressed file will be incorrect and the decompressed file will be empty. Thanks @Erik for pointing this out!

Answer (score 13):

I use this class for compressing/decompressing:

```
internal class GZipProcessor : IZipProcessor
{

    public byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                zipStream.Close();
                return compressedStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
                    return resultStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And how i can use it:

```
public void Compress(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    byte[] originalBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputPath);
    byte[] zippedBytes = base.ZipProcessor.Compress(originalBytes);
    File.WriteAllBytes(outputPath, zippedBytes);
}

public void Decompress(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    byte[] zippedBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputPath);
    byte[] originalBytes = base.ZipProcessor.Decompress(zippedBytes);
    File.WriteAllBytes(outputPath, originalBytes);
}
```

also i have a [github repository](https://github.com/isxaker/) with more complex code

Answer (score 3):

```
why FileStream works and memory doesn't
```

Because backing store of MemoryStream is your RAM memory, not hard drive. So when you passing `MemoryStream` object to `GZipStream` constructor, you gzip will be just in RAM.

With this code:

```
using (FileStream fs =new FileStream(this.newFileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
```

you are creating new FileStream, but you did not use it. To store gzip using this FIleStream, you need to pass it to `GZipStream` constructor, to make it backing store to be hard drive.